# Orbital integrals of $\operatorname{SL}_2$ and the fundamental lemma

Tags: rt.representation-theory, reductive-groups, langlands-conjectures, p-adic-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$When I was checking some orbital integral computations of Sally-Shalika's *[The Plancherel Formula for $\SL_2$ over a Local Field](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.63.3.661)*, Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences of the United States of America, Vol. 63, No. 3 (Jul. 15, 1969), pp. 661–667, I found something strange.

Let $k$ be a $p$-adic field with prime $p>2$, with ring of integers $R$ and residue field order $q$. Let $G=\SL_2(k)$ and $K=\SL_2(R)$. Let $\epsilon$ be a primitive $(q-1)$-th root of unity of $k$, and
$$T=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} x& y\\ \epsilon y & x\end{bmatrix}\ \middle\vert\ x^2-\epsilon y^2=1;~x,y\in k\right\}\subset K$$
an unramified anisotropic torus of $G$.

For a regular element $\gamma\in T$ and $f$ a smooth function on $G$, denote by $O_{\gamma}(f)$ the orbital integral
$$O_{\gamma}(f)=\int_{G/T}f(g\gamma g^{-1})d\dot{g},$$
where the measure on $G/T$ is the standard quotient measure: $KT/T$ has volume $1$.

In Sally–Shalika's paper p. 665 they obtained the following result of the orbital integral: for $\gamma\in T$ regular and close enough to $1$,
$$O_{\gamma}(f)=\frac{q+1}{2q^2}\cdot \begin{cases}|\gamma-\gamma^{-1}|^{-1/2}-1,&\text{if }|\gamma-\gamma^{-1}|=q^{-h}, h\equiv 1\pmod 2\\ q^{-1}\cdot|\gamma-\gamma^{-1}|^{-1/2}-1,&\text{if }|\gamma-\gamma^{-1}|=q^{-h}, h\equiv 0\pmod 2.\end{cases}$$

This made me puzzeled. Here $T$ is an unramified endoscopic group of $G$, and for a regular $\gamma\in T$, there're two rational conjugacy classes in its stable conjugacy class, namely $\gamma$ and $\gamma^{-1}$. Then the famous fundamental lemma tells us that there is a transfer factor $\Delta(\gamma)$ such that
$$\Delta(\gamma)(O_{\gamma}(f)-O_{\gamma^{-1}}(f))=f^T(\gamma),$$
where $f^T$ should be the constant function $1$ on the compact (elliptic) endoscopic group $T$ (cf. Kaletha's notes *[Lectures on the stable trace formula, with emphasis on $\SL_2$](https://public.websites.umich.edu/%7Ekaletha/singapore.pdf)*, p. 24).

But now by Sally–Shalika's results the left hand side seems to be zero. What's wrong with this computation? (I think this must be a very basic and well-known example, so experts must be very familiar with that. I have not checked whether Labesse–Langlands computed them explicitly.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\gamma$ and $\gamma^{-1}$ are rationally conjugate, by $\begin{pmatrix} i \\ & -i \end{pmatrix}$ if $q \equiv 1 \pmod4$ and $\begin{pmatrix} & \sqrt{-\epsilon^{-1}} \\ \sqrt{-\epsilon} \end{pmatrix}$ otherwise, so certainly the orbital integrals must agree. There is a stable-but-not-rational conjugate of $\gamma$ in a different torus, the one described in case (iii) of Lemma 2, which initially looks identical but has the cases switched, so that the difference does not vanish.

(Also, Lemma 2 is about congruence subgroups $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \equiv \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \pmod{\tau^m}\right\}$ with $m \ge 1$.  It looks like you mean to apply it with $m = 0$, but that's not claimed in the statement.)

Comment: Oh my God you are right! Thanks a lot! I didn't realize that the $p$-adic case is completely different from the real case: for ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, the stable conjugacy class of $k(\theta):=\begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta\\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta\end{bmatrix}$ contains $k(\theta)$ and its inverse $k(-\theta)$. But the $p$-adic case is not the same.

Comment: By the way is there any literature containing the orbital integral for the characteristic function of $K$ (i.e. $m=0$)? I have not yet checked Labesse-Langlands. (For $\gamma$ close enough to $1$ it suffices to use the germ expansion by Sally-Shalika, but I think there should be a general formula computed by someone.)

Comment: @youknowwho, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463275/orbital-integrals-of-operatornamesl-2-and-the-fundamental-lemma/463285#comment1202793_463285), not off the top of my head, no, but I'd be surprised if it weren't out there somewhere.